# Get text from a grand-child using XPath and contains function

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I've the below XML.

```
<section level="sect1">
    <title>
      <page num="1150"/>
      <content-style font-style="bold">ORDER 62</content-style>
      <content-style format="smallcaps">Costs</content-style>
    </title>
</section>
```

Here i want to check if the `title` has word `ORDER` in it.

I've tried

```
contains(//section[1]/title[1]/content-style[1]/text(),'ORDER')
```

but there are instances where the string `ORDER` might be in 2nd content-style` or in some might be in 3rd.

please let me know a generic way of finding it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
exists(//section[1]/title/content-style[contains(., 'ORDER')])
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> contains(//section[1]/title[1]/content-style[1]/text(),'ORDER')
> ```

You do a `contains` on the whole path, explicitly saying, in this expression, to get the first of each element with `[1]`. Instead, from your description you want *the child `content-style` that has "ORDER"* in it, which you should do as follows:

```
//section[1]/title[1]/content-style[text() = 'ORDER']
```

Or, if whitespace can be added:

```
//section[1]/title[1]/content-style[normalize-space(text()) = 'ORDER']
```

If the result is non-empty, you have found at least one "ORDER" in any `content-style` below `title[1]`, below `section[1]`.

> **get grand child text from grand parent element**

This was your question title. It is slightly different from what you wrote. If you want to check for *any grand-child `content-style` from `section`* then do this:

```
//section[1]/*/content-style[normalize-space(text()) = 'ORDER']
```

---

Final note: you tagged your original question as [xslt](/questions/tagged/xslt), in XSLT, an if-condition does not need to be a boolean, so:

```
<xsl:if test="//section[1]/*/content-style[normalize-space(text()) = 'ORDER']">
    <hello>found it!</hello>
</xsl:if>
```

is equal to wrapping the whole thing in `contains`, except that with `contains` you would be checking to a string combined of all elements, which would also mach *'no such ORDER'*, for instance.

The above is also similar to:

```
<!-- in place of xsl;if -->
<xsl:apply-templates select="//section[1]/*/content-style" />

<!-- place this at root level anywhere -->
<xsl:template match="content-style[normalize-space(text()) = 'ORDER']">
    <hello>found it!</hello>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="content-style">
    <hello>Not an order!</hello>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Here i want to check if the `title` has word `ORDER` in it.
>
> I've tried
>
> ```
> contains(//section[1]/title[1]/content-style[1]/text(),'ORDER')
> ```
>
> but there are instances where the `ORDER might be in 2nd`
>   content-style` or in some might be in 3rd.
>
> please let me know a generic way of finding it.

**Here is one XPath 1.0 expression that produces exactly the wanted Boolean value**:

```
boolean((//section)[1]/title[1][content-style[contains(., 'ORDER')]])
```

This produces `true()` exactly when there is at least one `content-style` element that is a child of a `title` element that is the first child of the first `section` element in the XML document.

**And a corresponding XPath 2.0 expression**:

```
exists((//section)[1]/title[1][content-style[contains(., 'ORDER')]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to obtain all the text from below the "title" node. The following should work:

```
contains(//section[1]/title[1]/string(.),'ORDER')
```

at least according to [this reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256133%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: No, this is not the same, as it will also include text in `page`, any mixed content in `title[1]` and possibly other elements at that level.